# что делать с ошибкой TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python

Задача: Найти сумму четных елементов списка и отдельно не четных. Вродебы все правильно но програмы выдает ошибку TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting. Что не так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Никогда! Никогда не выкладывайте [код картинкой](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12119/183314). Вот как мне понять, что там происходит?

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, не называйте переменные именами встроенных функций (`list`, `str`). Во-вторых `input` всегда возвращает строку, для строк символ `%` используется для постановки переменных в форматируемую строку, а placeholder-ов для помещения переменной в этой строке нет. Вот и получаете ошибку. Для выполнения математических операций ввод нужно преобразовывать в число. Ваш код может выглядеть так:

```py
elements = list(map(int, input())) # преобразуем ввод в список чисел
even = 0
not_even = 0
for el in elements:
    if el % 2 == 1:
        not_even += 1
    elif el == 0 or el % 2 == 0:
        even += 1

print(elements)
print(even)
print(not_even)
```

Answer (score 0):

Раз выдаёт ошибку — значит, не правильно. Проблема в вашем коде из-за того, что слева от оператора `%` в переменной `i` оказывается строка из одного символа.

```
print("введите последовательность чисел через пробел и нажмите Enter")
sequence = map(int, input().split())

even, uneven = 0, 0
for number in sequence:
    if number % 2:
        uneven += number
    else:
        even += number

print(f"сумма чётных   = {even}")
print(f"сумма нечётных = {uneven}")
```